Downcast with swig director classes
I have the following C++ code
class CPPSession
{
};

class CPPModule
{
    virtual CPPSession* create_session()
    {
        return new CPPSession;
    }
    virtual void do_something(CPPSession* session)
    {
    }
};

In my SWIG interface file I have enabled director feature for both CPPSession and CPPModule.
In C# I want to achieve the following
class CSSession : CPPSession
{
}

class CSModule : CPPModule
{
    public override CPPSession create_session()
    {
        return new CSSession();
    }

    public override void do_something(CPPSession session)
    {
        CSSession custom_session = (session as CSSession);
    }
}

Further, I have the following C++ code that works fine
CPPModule* module = create_cs_module();
CPPSession* session = module->create_session(); // calls CSModule::create_session
module->do_something(session); // calls CSModule::do_something(CPPSession)

NOTE: I'm not providing details of the create_cs_module function here because it has little to do with my question. All you need to know is that create_cs_module creates a CSModule object and returns a CPPModule* that points to this object.
The problem occurs in CSModule::do_something when I try to downcast. The custom_session value turns out to be null, which means that the downcast failed.
What should I change so that the downcast succeeds and I get the object that I created in CSModule::create_session?

when I try to downcast downcast what to what? Nothing on the C++ side in the given example shows signs of an inheritance hierarchy, so using a dynamic_cast would fail to convert.

Downcast from CPPSession to CSSession, please see CSModule::do_something.

Apologies. I came here off the C++ tag, and totally ignored the C# side of the question.
